# Getting error while running spring boot jar from systemd service in linux

Tags: spring-boot, corda

Hi guys i am getting this error:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile-Appender" for logger config "root"
main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile-Appender" for logger config "net.corda"
```

Service file:

```
[Unit] Description=Webserver for Corda Node - Notary Requires=network.target [Service] Type=simple User=corda WorkingDirectory=/opt/corda/Notary ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/corda/Notary/corda-webserver.jar Restart=on-failure [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Webserver for Corda Node -  Notary
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=corda
WorkingDirectory=/opt/corda/Notary
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/corda/Notary/corda-webserver.jar
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: this is my service file

Comment: Don't add information using comments, edit your question and add additional info

Answer (score 0):

your `log4j2.xml` configuration is trying to use an appender (`RollingFile-Appender`) that has not been defined. Add this to `log4j2.xml` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's already added there must be some other reason